Problema com método POST usando React com PHP de back-end
Comecei a usar React recentemente e estou um pouco com dores de cabeça para fazer um simples CRUD com PHP com MySQL, onde na minha aplicação React eu envio para o cadastrar.php, porém da erro no método POST, observem que estou usando método post no formulário, observem abaixo no app.js:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './estilo.css'; // arquivo css

function Formulario({ onSubmit }) {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    idCadastro: '',
    versao: '',
    encapsulamento: '',
    processador: '',
    memoria: '',
    pessoaResponsavel: '',
    mac: '',
    dataMontagem: '',
    dataValidacao: '',
    observacao: '',
    opcionais: '',
    softwareEmbarcado: false,
    etiquetagem: false,
    testeBancada: false,
    liberado: false,
    sensorTemperatura: false,
    producao: false
  });

  const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState(null); // Estado para armazenar os resultados da busca

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value, type, checked } = e.target;
    setFormData(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: type === 'checkbox' ? checked : value
    }));
  }; 

 //cadastrar dando erro, onde ele envia mas no php da erro de método post.
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(formData); 

  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost/cadastrar.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      alert('Dados enviados com sucesso!');
    } else {
      throw new Error('Erro ao enviar os dados.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao enviar os dados:', error);
  }
};


  //pesquisar coletor está funcionando perfeitamente
  const handleSearch = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost/pesquisar.php?id=${formData.id}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data.error) {
        alert(data.error);
      } else {
        setSearchResult(data); // Armazena os resultados da busca no estado searchResult
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Erro ao buscar dados:', error);
    }
  };

  // botão de limpar pesquisa
  const handleClearSearch = () => {
    setSearchResult(null); // Limpa os resultados da busca
  };

  return (
    <div className={'container'}>
      <div className={'crud'}>
        <label>
          Pesquisar pelo id:
          <input type='text' name="id" value={formData.id} onChange={handleChange} />
        </label>
        <button onClick={handleSearch}>Pesquisar</button>
        <button>Editar</button>
      </div>

      {/* Exibir resultados da busca aqui */}
      {searchResult && (
        <div>
          <h2>Resultados da Busca:</h2>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(searchResult, null, 2)}</pre>
          <button className={"button"} onClick={handleClearSearch}>Limpar Pesquisa</button> {/* Botão de limpar pesquisa */}
        </div>
      )}

      <details>
        <summary>Cadastrar nova coleta</summary>
        <h1>Cadastro de coletor</h1>
        <form method={'POST'} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className={'trio'}>
            <label>
              ID:
              <input type="text" name="idCadastro" value={formData.idCadastro} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Versão:
              <input type="text" name="versao" value={formData.versao} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Encapsulamento:
              <input type="text" name="encapsulamento" value={formData.encapsulamento} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
          </div>

          <div className={'trio'}>
            <label>
              Processador:
              <input type="text" name="processador" value={formData.processador} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Memória:
              <input type="text" name="memoria" value={formData.memoria} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Responsável:
              <input type="text" name="pessoaResponsavel" value={formData.pessoaResponsavel} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
          </div>

          <div className={'trio'}>
            <label>
              MAC:
              <input type="text" name="mac" value={formData.mac} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Montagem:
              <input type="date" name="dataMontagem" value={formData.dataMontagem} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Validação:
              <input type="date" name="dataValidacao" value={formData.dataValidacao} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
          </div>

          <div className={'trio'}>
            <label>
              Observação:
              <textarea name="observacao" value={formData.observacao} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Opcionais:
              <textarea name="opcionais" value={formData.opcionais} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
          </div>

          <div className={'trio'}>
            <label>
              Embarcado:
              <input type="checkbox" name="softwareEmbarcado" checked={formData.softwareEmbarcado} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Etiquetagem:
              <input type="checkbox" name="etiquetagem" checked={formData.etiquetagem} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Bancada:
              <input type="checkbox" name="testeBancada" checked={formData.testeBancada} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
          </div>

          <div className={'trio'}>
            <label>
              Liberado:
              <input type="checkbox" name="liberado" checked={formData.liberado} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Temperatura:
              <input type="checkbox" name="sensorTemperatura" checked={formData.sensorTemperatura} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Produção:
              <input type="checkbox" name="producao" checked={formData.producao} onChange={handleChange} />
            </label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </form>
      </details>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Formulario;


E aqui a lógica do PHP (cadastrar.php):
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    // Responde a solicitações OPTIONS com status 200 (OK)
    http_response_code(200);
    exit();
}

// Verifica se a requisição é POST
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Conecta-se ao banco de dados
    $servername = "localhost"; 
    $username = "root"; 
    $password = ""; 
    $dbname = "banco_teste"; 

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Verifica se a conexão foi estabelecida com sucesso
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Erro de conexão com o banco de dados: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // Prepara as declarações SQL para inserir os dados do formulário no banco de dados
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO coletor (id, versao, encapsulamento, processador, memoria, pessoaResponsavel, mac, data_montagem, data_validacao, observacao, opcionais, softwareEmbarcado, etiquetagem, testeBancada, liberado, sensorTemperatura, producao) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    // Associa os parâmetros com os valores dos campos do formulário
    $stmt->bind_param("isssssssssssiiiiii", $_POST['idCadastro'], $_POST['versao'], $_POST['encapsulamento'], $_POST['processador'], $_POST['memoria'], $_POST['pessoaResponsavel'], $_POST['mac'], $_POST['dataMontagem'], $_POST['dataValidacao'], $_POST['observacao'], $_POST['opcionais'], $_POST['softwareEmbarcado'], $_POST['etiquetagem'], $_POST['testeBancada'], $_POST['liberado'], $_POST['sensorTemperatura'], $_POST['producao']);

    // Executa a declaração preparada e verifica se foi bem-sucedida
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Cadastro realizado com sucesso!";
    } else {
        echo "Erro ao cadastrar: " . $stmt->error;
    }

    // Fecha a declaração e a conexão com o banco de dados
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
} else {
    // Caso a requisição não seja POST, retorna uma mensagem de erro
    echo "Método não permitido. Utilize o método POST para cadastrar os dados.";
}
?

onde sempre cai aqui: "Método não permitido. Utilize o método POST para cadastrar os dados.". Já tentei de tudo, mas nada deu certo.

Podem ser muitas coisas, um exemplo de problema é algum .htaccess mal-configurado no servidor que está rodando o PHP e como provavelmente está rodando o React e o PHP no mesmo servidor, é possivel que tenha feito algo especifico pro React  que afetou o comportamento dos redirecionamentos internos. Revise a pergunta original e as orientações fornecidas para melhora-la, os comentários também devem ser feitos na pergunta original.
